# Input text and Img reposition with Keyboard in Mobile View

Tags: jquery, css

My element moves with popping up of Android keyboard even with a a fixed position. Is there any way to prevent it?

```
s {
border: none;
display: none;
color: #9298a2;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
position: absolute;
top: 600px;
left: 19%;
width: 600px;
z-index: 1;
font-size: 75px;
background-color: white;
```

}

Github link: https://github.com/shaz13/Google-Home-Page
Demo at: http://www.mohammadshahebaz.com/gpage/
Any help would be appreciated. Looking for any workaround. I am using jQuery.